# Web Service asmx Xamarin.Form doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, xamarin.forms

My application Android display this error : "Object reference not set an instance of an object" when I execute my code. 
It's as if there was nothing in "e.Result". However, My webservice works well

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Please.GardaSoapClient Ws = new Please.GardaSoapClient(new BasicHttpBinding(),
                        new EndpointAddress("http://webgarda20170508110006.azurewebsites.net/Garda.asmx"));
            Ws.HelloCompleted += Ws_HelloCompleted;
            Ws.HelloAsync();

            }

        private void Ws_HelloCompleted(object sender, Please.HelloCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                    string error = null;
                     if (e.Error != null)
                         error = e.Error.Message;
                     else if (e.Cancelled)
                         error = "Cancelled";

                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                     {
                         await DisplayAlert("Error", error, "OK", "Cancel"); **//error => "Object reference not set an instance of an object"**
                     }
                     else 
             `enter code here`       {

                test.Text = e.Result;
               }
            });
        }
    }
```

Can you help me ? :)
Thanks

Comment: I haven't investigate this, but you can always do the http request manually. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/1845593

Comment: Another thing you can do, is to send the request over Fiddler and check the errors that are coming from the server or if you are hitting the server

Answer (score 0):

As the target method is an event handler, you can Take advantage of the async event handler to keep the event arg `e` in scope.

```
private async void Ws_HelloCompleted(object sender, Please.HelloCompletedEventArgs e) {
    string error = null;
    if (e.Error != null)
        error = e.Error.Message;
    else if (e.Cancelled)
        error = "Cancelled";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", error, "OK", "Cancel");
    } else {
        test.Text = e.Result;
    }
}
```